# Swiss german or usable?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Could we say "It's a **gift/ present** to meet you." or is this impossible to use?

Thx.

Comment: You could say it but no native English speaker would. It's not idiomatic. Prefer **pleased/delighted/thrilled to meet you**.

Comment: The idiomatic standard for your construction is *It's a **pleasure** to meet you.* More deferentially / sycophantically, *It's an **honour** to meet you.*

Comment: I don't understand the title of this question.  Could you explain the title?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your sentence is not idiomatic English.  It is more natural to say:

> It is a **pleasure / delight / thrill** to meet you.

or using the verb

> I am **pleased / delighted / thrilled** to meet you.

That being said, it's less common but quite easy to rephrase the sentence to use *present* or *gift*:

> Meeting you has been such a **gift**!  I was feeling so down, but you've really lifted my spirits.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fumble fingers. It functions idiomatically.

Compare:

> "You're an absolute rose" (The Great Gatsby)

and

> "You're an absolute gem!"

In both cases, they're not meant to be taken in the literal sense. Though pleasure / delight and thrill may be preferred in:

> It's a _______ to meet you.

Also you could get away with "It's a gift to meet you" but not  possibly, "It's a present to meet you". It just sounds unnatural.